# SkuAttributes in Sku Object in broadleaf is not coming in response

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

In broadleaf, I can see that the sku contains the `skuAttributes`. But when I try to invoke the product info using the endpoint `/catalog/product/{id}..` am do not see the `skuAttributes` coming in the api response. How can I get those sku attributes values as part of the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to override the `SkuWrapper` bean in an `@Configuration` class. Example:

```
@Configuration
public class ApiWrapperOverrides {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public MySkuWrapper blSkuWrapper() {
        return new MySkuWrapper();
    }
}

public class MySkuWrapper extends SkuWrapper {

    @XmlElement(name = "skuAttribute")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "skuAttributes")
    protected List<SkuAttributeWrapper> skuAttributes = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void wrapDetails(Sku model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        super.wrapDetails(sku, request);
        if (model.getSkuAttributes() != null && !model.getSkuAttributes().isEmpty()) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, SkuAttribute> entry : model.getSkuAttributes().entrySet()) {
                wrapper.wrapSummary(entry.getValue(), request);
                skuAttributes.add(wrapper);
            }
        }
    }
}
```